# How to read and modify a csv file on one bucket in cloud storage and save the results in another bucket using Cloud Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have CSV files coming to a folder on a Cloud Storage bucket and I want to create a Cloud Function that opens the CSV, adds a new column to it and then save the results to a new bucket as new.csv file.

Is there a way to do that using python Cloud Function???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say yes probably: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions-writing-background-hello-storage-python

Comment: How long is your file? Which size?

Comment: files does not exceed 10 MB !

Comment: @alex  Thnak you for the tips but is it possible for you to direct me to an example where I can understand how does it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that you’re trying to implement is totally possible and can be achieved using **Google Cloud Functions**.

For that, you would need to create a [**storage-triggered Cloud Function**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). More specifically, you can create your function in a way that it will respond to change notifications emerging from your Google Cloud Storage.

These notifications can be configured to respond to various *events* inside a bucket: object **creation**, **deletion**, **archiving** and **metadata updates**.

For the situation described, you will need to use the trigger `google.storage.object.finalize`.
This event is sent when a **new object is created** in the bucket or an **existing object is overwritten**, and a new generation of that object is created.

[**Here**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-tabs) you can find a sample code of a storage-triggered Cloud Function written in Python, while this [**tutorial**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-function2sheet/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) will give you a more detailed overview of the usage of storage-triggered functions.